# Do I need nodejs or I can rely only on Nginx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, nginx

I have an application and I have a debate with my peers on if we need to use node.js or not.

- Our decision is to use angular.js for the front-end and to communicate via REST api with the app server. *The application server will not be in node.js. It could be in .net or Java*
- Nginx will be in front as it is better for serving static files, gzip etc..

There are many options to boilerplate your angular application and many of them includes nodejs. My first approach was to use node.js as the primary web server and scale it out for solving performance issues. Although, it wasn't a good approach as node's roles isn't to act as web server. Well, here my question arrives.

By keeping in mind the two aforementioned points are there any reasons to generate the front-end including node.js ?

Is there something that I could benefited by that I haven't think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the short answer: If you are set on using nginx in front of a .net or Java back end, and you're just looking for a deployment tool for angular.js, then just choose whatever javascript deployment tool makes sense, which may well be built with node.

What follows is a little more exposition:

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "node's roles isn't to act as web server"... if you mean in general, then that's precisely how it's generally used, if you mean your application server will be .net or java, but not javascript, then fine.

Generally speaking, nginx will perform faster for static files, but the margin of improvement over node.js is likely to be meaningless for pretty much anyone.  If you need to (or it makes sense to) include node as part of your stack for angular deployment, then it could make sense to use it as your reverse proxy and just eliminate nginx altogether.  The odds that you'll get measurable benefit from using nginx instead is vanishingly small.

That said... if you've already got nginx set up and moving to node instead represents extra work that you've already done once, then it loses its primary appeal.

What node.js has going for it more than any other project I'm aware of is that it's extremely capable at *every* level of the web stack.  But it's not necessarily *more* capable than individual projects used in their appropriate level of the stack, and if you're not going to use it to reduce the complexity of your stack by homogenizing the technology and applications involved, then it just comes down to preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are caring about performance especially for static files, you could add caching layer as a proxy in front of your backend nginx or a server of your choice .. [Varnish-cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) is a good choice.

If you want to serve static files at large scale, there is yet a better solution through which you could host your static files in CDNs that will be much better solutions for your live deployments .. Clouding services are built for ease of use and also cost effective for example [fastly.com](http://fastly.com) is a good choice for hosting static files with a very persistent cached layer that is built on top of [Varnish-Cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) .. [Cloud front](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) is also another choice if you are fan of Amazon services.

More resources that might help is a [comparison benchmarks](http://www.techtatva.com/2010/09/apache-2-cherokee-lighttpd-nginx-benchmarked-with-static-files-php5-script-and-wordpress/) having popular servers, also another benchmark exists[here](http://www.wjunction.com/64-webmaster-resources/81962-apache-vs-nginx-vs-lighttpd-cherokee.html)